# How can i change the color of the case subject or any other field as per time for SLA?

Tags: case, formula-field, service-cloud-console, image-formula

I am working to change the color of the case subject or any other field  with respect to the time. I have tried the formula fields for same. But I am not sure how to change the color.

For Example, if there is task to be completed in 18 hours. I want this to appear normal, After 5 hours, the color for case statement should change to yellow, then after 15 hours it should change to blue. After 18 hours, it should change to Red.

Comment: The color of what?

Comment: Color of the case statement with respect to the time

Comment: I don't think you can manipulate colors in a formula but you can use [colored images](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=useful_advanced_formulas_image_links.htm&language=en_US) for that purpose.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I do think there are some color options available in the service cloud console. Is this what your questions is about ? Providing more detail and context in your question (edit/update) will help us help you.

Comment: When you refer to 'case statement', what do you mean? Could you provide a screenshot to show what you want to change the colour of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition of already said by sfdcfox I would like to show you an example of the formula field that you should add.

1. Add 3 images as statics resources and name them: yellowFlag, blueFlag, redFlag
2. Add a custom field type formula and use this:

   `IF( ( Now() - CreatedDate )*24 > 18 , 
    IMAGE("/resource/RedFlag", "red" ,30, 30) ,
   IF( ( Now() - CreatedDate )*24 < 15,
    IMAGE("/resource/BlueFlag", "blue" ,30, 30),
   IMAGE("/resource/YellowFlag", "yellow" ,30, 30))
   )`

Key points:

- `(Now() - CreatedDate) *24`  == record's age in hours
- `IMAGE("/resource/YellowFlag", "yellow" ,30, 30))` == will show the image that set

Sample:

[image]

Comment: What if I have different business hours... How will I take that into picture...

Comment: If you are referring to different GMT by user, It will work fine because SF manage CreationDate and Now as timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

For the standard case number field, the only thing you can really do is escalate the case based on escalation rules. This adds a red arrow next to the case number when the system escalates the case.

For colors or other cool tricks, use a formula field. There's actually an example of a case flag formula in the Help & Training area [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/usefulFormulaFields/Content/useful_advanced_formulas_image_links.htm). You'll have to determine what you mean by SLA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streaming API to retrieve data in real-time and To receive notifications on the SLA MET field or SLA TIMELEFT, the subscriber must subscribe to those fields referenced in the query.

Go through the below document and the supported push topics, you will get a clear picture.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/